# PostgreSql - How to create conditional column with the filter on another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to add 1 more columns where segment out whether the customer had sold at least one product or not.
Data example:

```
ProductID    Customer     Status
1            John         Not sold
2            John         Not Sold
3            John         Sold
```

My expect result

```
ProductID    Customer     Status         Sold_at_least_1
1            John         Not sold       Yes
2            John         Not Sold       Yes
3            John         Sold           Yes
4            Andrew       Not Sold       No
5            Andrew       Not Sold       No
6            Brandon      Sold           Yes
```

This is an example data. Sorry for any inconvenience as I unable to extract data out. Btw, appreciating for any helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a window count of records of the same customer that have `status = 'Sold'` in a `case` expression:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    case when sum( (status = 'Sold')::int ) over(partition by customer) >= 1
        then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end
from mytable
```

NB: note that this does not magically create new records (as shown in your sample data). This query gives you as many records in the resultset as there are in the table, with an additionnal column that indicates whether each cutsomer has at least one sold item in the table.

Here is [a demo provided by VBokšić](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f37f3dc483d68dbba95f7ff0b55c0169) (thanks).

Comment: @VBokšić: here `sum()` is used as a window function, not a regular aggregate function (there is an `over()` clause). So there is no `group by` clause.

Comment: "group by department,company" + "partition by customer" + "status = 'Sold'" gives us 4 columns ? And we have only ProductID    Customer     Status and company and department are not among them...

Comment: Just want to help ;)

Comment: @VBokšić: ah yes my bad, I did not pay attention, that’s a copy/paste issue. Fixed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Now this works - vote up from me. Here you can use this demo if you want in your answer... Or arrange it then use it :) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f37f3dc483d68dbba95f7ff0b55c0169

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `bool_or()` as a window function. If you can live with a `boolean` column rather than a varchar with Yes/No, this makes the expression even simpler:

```
select productid, customer, status, 
       bool_or(status = 'Sold') over (partition by customer) as sold_at_least_one
from mytable;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/NDN54253

Comment: Or you can wrap the `bool_or()` function in a `case expression` if you want `Yes/No` in the resultset.

Comment: Sorry but I encounter this matter - "Detail: Bit-wise aggregate functions cannot be used as window functions and do not support the OVER() clause (pid:12687"

Comment: @ChauLoi: then you are using an outdated Postgres version. The online example works just fine with Postgres 9.6